# Can i send one form ListView item to another form ListView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 form 1st form has one ListView and a Button. 2nd Form has same thing. I want to send 1st form`s ListView selected item to 2nd Form`s listview

1st form code:

```
public void UpdateListView(ListView source, ListView target)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in source.SelectedItems)
    {
        target.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateListView(form1ListView,form2ListView);
}
```

2nd form code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1.show();
}
```

But i cannot use form2ListView in form1. How can i do this? My 2nd form ListView name is form2ListView.

Comment: the form2_button click will open form one, then how it is possible to have `form1ListView` as source

Comment: change the form1's list view to being public. Then you can access it once you create an instance of it.

Comment: CathaIMF when listview make public then no error but i cannot get item

Answer (score 0):

just pass the whole form into the Form1 as a parameter

```
 Form1 form1 = new Form1(form2);
```

Comment: are you sure about the op's `Form1` have a constructor that accept one parameter of type `Form2`

Comment: I know it's a stupid solution, though - such was the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply provide the `ListView` of `Form2` as constructor argument for `Form1`:

```
public partial class Form1
{
    private readonly ListView form2ListView;

    public Form1() { //... default initialization }

    // constructor with ListView as argument
    public Form1(ListView _form2ListView)
    {
         form2ListView = _form2ListView;
    }
}
```

Then you can instantiate that `Form1` like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1(myListView); // don't know how your ListView is named
    form1.show();
}
```